# Gathering the default landing page URL for a large ip hostlist on a single port

Tags: python, linux, bash, nmap, penetration-testing

### So here is the requirement breakdown:

- Parse NMAP output to define a hostlist that is serving web services.
- Use a hostlist to define the default landing page URL for each listening protocol.
- Compile a master web services list to include IP:URL.

### What I have done so far:

- Generated a hostlist that includes all hosts listening for HTTP/S traffic. Each hostlist is separated by port/ssl usage.

### What I am having trouble with:

- It seems logical to be able to do the following: Use a list with the IP of every host listening for http over port 80 to run a query as if we are typing *http://test.ip* into a browser and capturing the default URL it lands on. *http://test.url/index.html*
- I have tried to use cURL and Wget and worked a bit with Scrapy but I am not able to capture just the default landing page URL in a scripted fashion. All I need is a means to take a single IP and resolve only the default landing page URL for a single port. I can then integrate this function into a broadened script to run against each port/prot.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with all the extra parsing and tools if you're already scanning with Nmap? The [Nmap Scripting Engine](https://nmap.org/book/nse.html) can do what you want easily for each HTTP port discovered. You can even use an existing script: [http-title](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-title.html) will request the URL `/` and follow up to 5 redirects in order to retrieve the HTML title of the landing page. If a redirect is followed, it includes "Requested resource was */path*" to show what the actual landing page URL was.